# Error : Cache frontend 'default' is not recognized after upgrade Magento version in 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

When I ran Setup:upgrade command then below error showing
`InvalidArgumentException: Cache frontend 'default' is not recognized. in /vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php:150 Stack trace: #0`

What is solution?

Comment: Have you get solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to check the **value of cache** in **file app/etc/env.php**.
For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your `app/etc/env.php`, if necessary recreate it.